# Check wordpress url begins with certain string

Tags: wordpress, url, strpos

if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/arr/") !== false) {

}

I tried with the above condition.

http://localhost/wordpress/arr/ => executed

http://localhost/wordpress/arr/sample-page/ => not executed

I want to execute it for the second one as well.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a solution:

```
$paths = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

foreach($paths as $path){
if($path=='arr')
{
/*Do what you need*/
}
}
```

Comment: I tried like below as well. Same result. 
`$paths = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if ($paths[2] == "arr") { }`

Comment: do a print_r($paths) after the $paths declaration. What are the results?
Like this: $paths = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); print_r($paths) ;

Comment: I'm getting this `Array ( [0] => [1] => wordpress [2] => arr [3] => )`

Comment: try to compare with ===

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it will work.

```
if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "arr")!==false) 
{
   // Your code`enter code here`
}
```